# What does this Objective-C code snippet mean, and what document details it?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

Ok, so I've done searches in Xcode, on Apple's developer's site, and on google, and have even downloaded and searched pdf versions of the Key-Value Coding Programming Guide and Collections Programming Topics, but I cannot find this syntax listed anywhere.  What does the second line of the following snippet do, and where can I find the details on it?

```
NSMutableDictionary *change = [NSMutableDictionary new];
change[@(someVariable)] = @(someOtherVariable);
```

I don't know if I'm having a brain fart, or if I've actually never seen this before, but it really bugs me that I can't find documentation for it.

Comment: BTW: Xcode has a Refactor - Tool (Edit:Refactor) which has "Convert Code to modern Obj-C Syntax". If you have old syntax in your code this is a nice way to see what would change.

Comment: I'll have to keep the refactor tool in mind for the future. I like having stuff verbose when I'm learning it, but using the shorter modern syntax will be useful later when I'm used to it.

Comment: I agree. Anyway that tool works with the versions-editor so one can see the difference in a beautiful way and w/o having to apply them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually two things going on here:

1. Dictionary (and array) subscripting

   ```
   change[key]
   ```

   This is a new syntactic sugar for

   ```
   [change objectForKey:key]
   ```

   Or, if used as an lvalue, it is syntactic sugar for

   ```
   [change setObject:value forKey:key]
   ```

   For what's really going on here (`objectForKeyedSubscript:` and `setObject:forKeyedSubscript:`) see http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_nsdictionary_and_nsmutabledictionary
2. Number literals

   ```
   @(someVariable)
   ```

   This is a new compiler directive, equivalent to:

   ```
   [NSNumber numberWithInt: someVariable]
   ```

   Except that in fact it will use `numberWithInt:`, `numberWithFloat:`, or whatever is appropriate based on the type of `someVariable`.

   Again, see http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch10.html#_nsnumber

Comment: Ok, this is making more sense now.  One thing that particularly confused me is that the key appears to be an object, rather than a string, as I thought was required for key-value coding.  Looking through the documentation I mentioned above however, it appears that 'key' in the context of an NSMutableDictionary object is not the same as 'key' in the context of key-value coding.  Is it correct that these are two separate concepts?

Comment: I agree that this made the example more confusing. The dictionary key can be any object type meeting certain basic requirements. It does not have to be a string. But that has nothing to do with the syntax question you asked; it has always been true. It is *common* to use an NSString, but it is by no means required. See the start of https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html You are perfectly right that for KVC a string is needed.

Comment: First: In the Q, change[@(someVariable)] does not stand for [change objectForKey:key], but for [change setObject:… forKey:key]. It is similiar to dot notation ("rvalue" and "lvalue").

Comment: Second (sorry, editing run out): But it is not similiar to setObject:forKey: It is something new:
First of all, there is a new protocol for Keyed-Subscription. 
Second: Keyed-Subscription can be applied to potentially instances of every class. So in this point it is similiar to KVC, not to setObject:forKey:/objectForKey: (which is no KVC). But the key does not have to be a string. This is similar to setObject:forKey:/objectForKey:. The behaviour for object = nil is similar to setObject:forKey:, if the receiver is a dictionary. But remember that the receiver can be an instance of whatever.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer is getting down voted. It dissected the code snippet and revealed the different syntaxes at play. And provides references to boot. This is a good answer, and easily understood.  Come on, give it some love, guys.  Even if there's some technical inconsistency with it, it clearly conveys the general idea of what's happening, which is exactly what I, as an inexperienced programmer, was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This is the new syntax introduced in Objective C relatively recently. It is documented at [this link](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html).

Scroll down to *Object Subscripting* syntax for an explanation:

> Objective-C object pointer values can now be used with C’s subscripting operator.

Your code fragment translates as

```
[change setObject:@(someOtherVariable) forKeyedSubscript:@(someVariable)];
```

To support the new syntax described there, the Objective-C @-expression grammar has been introduced. The `@`-expression is explained at the bottom of the document.

Answer (score 1):

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html

Check out "[examples](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html#id3)" about half way through the doc